# Apply DataSource Loop to two excel sheets

Tags: soapui

I have a SoapUI script that is designed to compare two service calls. Right now all I have to use is the legacy service (the expected values). I'm calling the legacy system with a datasource to drive test cases.

I'm using a second datasouce as a **stub** to mimic the new service while it's being developed.

Looping through the legacy service data works fine with the one data source but the problem is when I try to access the second datasource in the loop, it won't iterate.

The test structure looks like this:

```
       Legacy DataSource
|----> Legacy Call
|      New Service Stub (Excel DataSource) 
|      Some Validation
|      DataSink (Trying to access the New Service Stub)
|<-----Legacy DataSource Loop
```

When I try to access the Service Stub (Excel sheet) from the DataSink, I only get blank values - it appears like the test step to retrieve the data is never running or SoapUI never increments the row #.

How can I step through the second datasource inside an existing loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have one DataSource loop somehow loop with two DataSource sadly. You can have a loop within a loop but that wouldn't fix things in your case.

You easiest option would be to put all of the information in one spreadsheet so that the DataSource is pulling in both the legacy call information as well as the new service information.

The harder way would be to control everything from a groovy script (All of the looping). Not impossible but the first suggestion is a lot faster if you just want to get up and running.